# Mediator Pattern when to register events

Tags: php, events, mediator

The problem with many design patterns for me always seems to be the best way to implement them within an existing code base.

The code base is PHP4 which is being migrated to PHP5 OOP.  However this is an on going process unlikely to be completed any time soon (users always want new features!).

With the Mediator pattern where should events be registered?

Should a directory be created with lots of scripts that register events,  this could then be loaded via the bootstrap.

```
//bootstrap.php
..
new \Listener\Something();
new \Listener\SomethingElse();
new \Listener\SomethingOtherThing();
```

Or would it be better to register events just before they might be triggered, there is the risk an event is triggered but has never been registered though.

```
//user.php
class User {
    ..
    function ageChange() {
        new \Listener\UserAge();
        ..
    }
    ..
}
```

Or is there a different approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to answer this question. It depends on case (and your case looks more like Observer pattern)

In my opinion it's better to create observer/listeners/mediator objects before they might be triggered.

1. You don't populate the global nameespace with lot's of classes
2. you don't waste memory to store objects that at the end probably won't be used
3. you don't waste cpu to create lot's of classes.
4. it's easy to modify a code behaviour and pass/create a different class. When everything is created in bootstrap you have to stick with that set

In some cases it's good to create everything during bootstrapping application. But to do that use a Service Locator pattern or Dependency Injection Pattern to inject patterns. For Dependency Injection I recommend Pimple library (http://pimple.sensiolabs.org/).

And my example of Mediator pattern written in PHP :
https://github.com/piotrmiazga/design_patterns/blob/master/src/Patterns/Mediator/Example.php

Comment: I agree with those points - however even if the Observer pattern was used instead, the same implementation issues persist.  For example a new Subject is created, when should new Observers be attached? If we have a CarSubject and a DoorObserver when do you create the CarSubject and attach the DoorObserver, new Car() { new CarSubject } but where do the Observers get attached?

Comment: You create them when you want to use them. If you have a observer that should be run always then you should set it as soon as possible. But this case is very rare. Normally you create a CarSubject, and when you're building car subject depending on capabilities you're attaching Observers. I'm trying to create and attach them as late as possible (I'm creating objects only when I'm sure that they are needed). Plus sometimes you need an subject with empty observers list, it's totally correct behaviour.

Comment: In the example of a Car; which has Doors, Windows etc.. I would like to have an Observer for the doors opening/closing, windows opening/closing etc.. What would this code actually look like? Sorry if I'm going a little off topic, I'm trying to get my head around it all.

Comment: I think the best way is making a Builder that creates a car object, and then on already built objects it would attach all needed observers, and then return properly build car.

Comment: Thanks I've gone for a mixed solution, not very happy with it but it seems to work. The event is only registered when the code is invoked, although I had to wrap it in a singleton to prevent a double register of the same event.

Comment: Case by case is different, if you want you can send me that one small part of code and I can check it for you